# Why Instagram followers retriever seldom works, most of times Invalid username?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, instagram-graph-api

When this code is running on chrome console with fresh Instagram login:
Code seldom works
Most of the time an Invalid username?

It seems most often after `console.log(url)` code breaks.

```
let username = 'miyakoho'
let followers = []
try {
  let res = await fetch('https://www.instagram.com/' + username + '/?__a=1')

  res = await res.json()
  let userId = res.graphql.user.id

  let after = null
  let has_next = true
  after = null
  while (has_next) {

    let url='https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=c76146de99bb02f6415203be841dd25a&variables=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
      id: userId,
      include_reel: true,
      fetch_mutual: true,
      first: 50,
      after: after
      }))

    console.log(url)

    await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
      has_next = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.has_next_page
      after = res.data.user.edge_followed_by.page_info.end_cursor
      followers = followers.concat(res.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(({node}) => {
        return {
          username: node.username,
          full_name: node.full_name
        }
      }))
    })
  }
  console.log('Followings', followings)
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Invalid username')
}
```

Comment: How does this question relate to TypeScript? I don't see any types, and the question seems to be about runtime behavior.

Comment: @jcalz I run it in chrome console or in main code getting the same result.